# React.js, syntax for handling promises?

Tags: reactjs, promise

what is the best way to handle promises in React.js? The code below works - is there a more reacty way?

```
handleFormSubmit(input){

    this.setState({
        originId: input.originId,
        destinationId: input.destinationId,
        radius: input.radius,
        search: input.search
    });

    var routeSearch = new FindRoutes({
        originPlaceId: input.originId,
        destinationPlaceId: input.destinationId,
        directionsDisplay: directionsDisplay,
        directionsService: directionsService,
        travel_mode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        search: input.search
    });

    routeSearch.execute()
    .then(function(){
        alert("promise fullfilled!");
    });

}
```

Comment: The code is fine. React is a view engine with DOM diffing you don't have to couple it to any architecture.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do. If you're looking for a good way to structure your actions and keep everything organized. I recently added redux to my project

http://redux.js.org/

And its brilliant, definitely recommend checking it out. They separate out the render logic from your actions(i.e promise in this case) using a methodology called flux

https://facebook.github.io/flux/